# vsftpd uses TLS1.1 even after disabling

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, vsftpd, rhel-6, lftp

I have disabled `TLS1.1` and `SSLv3` in my vsftpd.conf

```
ssl_tlsv1_1=NO
ssl_tlsv1_2=YES
ssl_tlsv1=NO
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
ssl_ciphers=DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:AES256-SHA256
```

But still when i use `lftp` from another machine and transfer data, i see `TLS1/SSLV3` being used.

```
"SSL version: TLSv1/SSLv3, SSL cipher: AES256-SHA256, reused, no cert"
```

I have no idea if i am missing some configuration.

vsftpd version:

```
# vsftpd -version
vsftpd: version 2.2.2
```

lftp version:

```
# lftp -v
LFTP | Version 4.0.9 | Copyright (c) 1996-2010 Alexander V. Lukyanov
```

Signature used in `pem` file that is used as certificate (Can't post more):

```
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

Comment: Tell us more about the certificate being used.

Comment: Done! But can you explain how does it matter?

Comment: Considering how these options simply do not exist, it is not surprising they do nothing.

Comment: http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html - i do see these options available

Comment: You can’t tell anything about which ciphers the certificate supports?  How it matters is, I suspect I know what’s happening, wanted to confirm that’s the case.

Comment: @Ramhound i have added the ciphers that i have enabled in my configuration if that is what you are asking

Comment: Neither `ssl_tlsv1_1` nor `ssl_tlsv1_1` are in the man page. They appear in internet guides though. Your version of vsftpd is also ~10 years old.

Comment: @DanielB: I see these options in the man page that was shipped with the vsftpd that i am using. I assume that means it is available in my version of vsftpd

Comment: @Fazlin - I am only interested in the ciphers for the certificate.  You used OpenSSL to create the certificate?

Comment: @Ramhound: yes i used openssl to create the pem file. If you have command that i can run to get that, it would be helpful.

Comment: I think i got the answer from this link: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71507/sslv3-is-still-showing-in-openssl-result-even-after-disabling-from-sslprotocol

Comment: @DanielB: Those options are added by Debian as distribution patches.